# Getting a 404 error when deploying production build

Tags: javascript, extjs4

I'm getting an error about `Application.js` not being found once I've copied the application over to a web server.

```
http://site/app/Application.js?_dc=1404504339794 404 (Not Found)
```

But obviously, this is wrong since once you run `sencha app build` everything is minified to `app.js`.

I looked at the generated `app.js` and `index.html` and there is no mention of `Application.js` anywhere.

I'm running: `sencha app build production` and copying the content of the `production` build over.

I am also getting a `C1009: Circular reference` warning during the build. And here it is:

in `/controller/MainContent.js` at line 192

```
var w = Ext.widget('EditPortalUserWindow'); //this creates a widget defined in the MainContent.js VIEW
```

And within that view at some point in one of the widgets, I use this to define the URL of a form:

```
url: GlobalVars.contactPostApiUrl //if I comment this out, the warning goes away...
```

`GlobalVars` is defined in `app.js`

```
Ext.define('GlobalVars', {
    singleton: true,
    contactPostApiUrl: 'http://site/CustomerPortal.WebAPI/api/contact/post'
});
```

I want GlobalVars to be available from everywhere, which is why I put it in app.js.

Any ideas ? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I have seen something similar already - the production build requiring files it shouldn't. The following should help:

1. run the development version and see if you get any synchronous loading warning, fix if yes.
2. run `sencha app build --clean`

If it does not help run this sequence

```
sencha ant clean
sencha app refresh
sencha app build
```

Comment: That did not help unfortunately. Although, I'm getting circular references warnings (`C1009: Circular reference in requirements chain`) during the build. I don't really know what these means and if they do make the build ultimately fail.

Comment: Hmmm, then it could be a stale cache, no other ideas... Btw, which Ext and Cmd versions?

Comment: I'm using Sencha Cmd v4.0.4.84 along with ExtJS 4.2.1

Comment: That is the latest of 4.x series, I'd expect least bugs in that version. Only those circular references stay as the last thing to fix.

Answer (score 0):

@Francis Ducharme Adding to the above coversation , i m sending u two links which i guess might help u with C1009 .
[C1009 Link 1](https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?283355-quot-C1009-Circular-reference-in-requirements-chain-quot-How-to-fix-it&p=1038203)

[C1009 Link 2](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?271723-Cmd-Compile-warning-quot-C1009-Circular-reference-quot)

Answer (score 0):

I "solved" this issue by actually creating the file it is looking for (an empty one) and this seems to work. Although I feel a bit uncomfortable with this fix.

Comment: Yeah, it solves consequences, not the cause. I'd still look in that circular references.

Comment: @Saki I figured this is not the best way to kick the can down the road. I've edited my question with more details about said warning.